# How to crop transparent (or even white) PNG?

Tags: png, crop

I would like to automatically crop a `foo.png` with either white or transparent background and ran into the warning (and actually error for transparent background) "mogrify: profile 'icc': 'RGB ':  RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG `foo.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1656."

`foo.png` is created in `R` via

```
x <- 1:10
y <- rev(x)
png(file=(file <- "crop.png"), bg="transparent")
plot(x, y, xlab="x", ylab="y")
dev.off()
```

If I then use either `mogrify -trim foo.png` or `convert foo.png -trim +repage foo_cropped.png`, I receive the above warning and the file is only cropped vertically, not horizontally (which should actually be viewed as an error). If I use `bg="white"`, then it is cropped on all sides but I still obtain the above warning. How can this be avoided? Ideally, I'm looking for a command line tool available in Linux and on the Mac which is able to crop `.png` files.

Comment: Try creating an RGBA PNG instead, using "png32:crop.png" for the output filename.  If the underlying image processor you are using is ImageMagick, it'll still create "crop.png" but the ICC profile should be acceptable.  ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick are available for Linux and Mac, and can crop .png files via a commandline.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. `mogrify -trim foo.png` then gives me no warning but the png is still only cropped vertically. The convert command creates the same (but still throws the warning). Any ideas? I'm using `ImageMagick 6.9.1-1 Q16 x86_64` on Mac OS X 10.11

Comment: Is it possible to trim the white space around the picture in R?

Comment: You can work with `par()` to set the margins, but I rather do that outside R. See my R package `crop` for that (I only tested this on my hardware, so it may or may not work for you), which essentially calls `mogrify` and other commands (`pdfcrop`, `epstool`) to do a perfect cropping.